# Python 2.7 - JavaError when using grammar-check 1.3.1 library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use the `grammar-check 1.3.1` library for Python

I have installed it using the pip commands

```
$ pip install --upgrade 3to2

$ pip install --upgrade language-check
```

I also unzipped the LanguageTool file from [this link](https://github.com/myint/language-check) and moved it to `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\grammar_check`

Then I tried to run a test program

```
import grammar_check as gc

with open("file.txt") as f:
    tool = gc.LanguageTool('en-US')
    matches = tool.check(f.read())
    print len(matches)
```

But I got this error

```
File "lang-grammar-checker.py", line 22, in main
tool = gc.LanguageTool(predicted)
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\grammar_check\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
self._start_server_on_free_port()
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\grammar_check\__init__.py", line 318, in _start_server_on_free_port
cls._start_server()
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\grammar_check\__init__.py", line 330, in _start_server
server_cmd = get_server_cmd(cls._port)
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\grammar_check\__init__.py", line 541, in get_server_cmd
java_path, jar_path = get_jar_info()
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\grammar_check\__init__.py", line 554, in get_jar_info
raise JavaError(u"can't find Java")
grammar_check.JavaError: can't find Java
```

I also have Java8 installed in my computer. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Do you have your java path defined in Environment variable PATH?

Comment: @avix I added to the PATH variable the value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin` but it is still not working

Comment: When you type `java -version` in command prompt does it show your Java version?
If so, is there any difference with error message?
@Edit: add jdk instead of jre :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your system can't see your java. You can check if your system "knows" java by typing:

```
java -version
```

in command prompt (without going to your java location!).
You can do it adding to your environment variable PATH your **java development kit** location.
[How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: Thanks! I was not using the jdk path location